# Can GCM send a push notification message to a VoIP iOS?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Does GCM support VoIP app on iOS?

I can't upload Certificate that using VoIP service into **Production APNS Certificate (P12 format)**.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: He's trying to send a voip push, since iOS has two kinds of push: apns and voip.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **No**.

But Amazon SNS supports VoIP push.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-push-send-apns-voip.html